# Where does my .sav file default to in XNA 4.0 when using the StorageDevice class?

Tags: xna, pc

I am using the StorageDevice class built into XNA and am looking to delete my save file from the solution in my XNA game.  I never specify where the save file is to save, and can't find the default location on MSDN documentation.  I am developing this game for the pc, and never prompt the user to select a save device. Where can I find the save file so that I may delete it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some high level details on storage in XNA can be found on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb200105.aspx).

The paragraph with the most relevance to your question would be:

> User storage is in the My Documents folder of the user who is currently logged in, in the SavedGames folder. A subfolder is created for each game according to the titleName passed to the BeginOpenContainer method. When no PlayerIndex is specified, content is saved in the AllPlayers folder. When a PlayerIndex is specified, the content is saved in the Player1, Player2, Player3, or Player4 folder, depending on which PlayerIndex was passed to BeginShowSelector.

The saved game file should be located within the SavedGames sub folder found within MyDocuments. You should find a folder hierarchy similar to that of the parameters you passed into your storage function calls.